# Conditional IF statement with lagged values

Tags: if-statement, sas, row, datastep

I have the following dataset, structured as follows:

```
DATE           PERCENTAGE    FLAG    VALUE1  
01JAN2017        0.21          1      1.50   
04JAN2017        0.05          0      2.43
09JAN2017        0.06          1      2.21
24JAN2017        0.15          1      1.13
```

I have to add new variables to the dataset such that those variables will fulfill the following condition:

1. in the case `FLAG` is equal to 1 and it's the first row then:

> ```
> NEW_VAR_1 is equal to 500 * PERCENTAGE;
> NEW_VAR_2 is equal to NEWVAR_1 * (VALUE1 - 1);
> NEW_VAR_3 is equal to 500 + NEWVAR_2;
> ```

2. In the case `FLAG` is equal to 1 and it's not the first row then:

> ```
> NEW_VAR_1 is equal to LAG(NEWVAR_3) * PERCENTAGE;
> NEW_VAR_2 is equal to NEWVAR_1 * (VALUE1 - 1);
> NEW_VAR_3 is equal to LAG(NEWVAR_3) + NEWVAR_2;
> ```

3. In the case `FLAG` is equal to 0 then all the `NEWVAR_` values have to be set on missing.

I need to run this script on SAS and I write the following script down to do that:

```
DATA BACKTESTING;
    SET BACKTESTING;
    IF _N_ EQ 1 AND FLAG EQ 1 THEN DO;
        K = 500;
        NEWVAR_1 = PERCENTAGE * K;
        NEWVAR_2 = NEWVAR_1 * (VALUE_1 - 1);
        NEWVAR_3 = K + NEWVAR_2;
    END;
    ELSE IF _N_ GT 1 AND FLAG EQ 1 THEN DO;
        NEWVAR_1 = PERCENTAGE * LAG(NEWVAR_3);
        NEWVAR_2 = NEWVAR_1 * (VALUE_1 - 1);
        NEWVAR_3 = K + NEWVAR_2; 
        END;
    END;
RUN;
```

The script works correctly, in the sense I did not see error or warning message in the log window, but, as you can note by reading the script, it returns missing values when it finds a missing values in the lagged variables.

Is there a way to overcome such problem, in order to be able letting SAS takes the lag of `NEWVAR_3` only when `FLAG` is equal to 1?

In the hope I've been clear enough in the question, thanks all in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `lag` is that it does not actually read the previous value.  Instead, it adds the current value to a hidden array every time it is called - which is then retrieved in subsequent calls.

So - if you do not call `lag` on every iteration (or call it twice) you will get unexpected results.

One way to avoid this is to use a simple `retain`, eg as follows:

```
DATA BACKTESTING;
  SET BACKTESTING;
  IF _N_ EQ 1 AND FLAG EQ 1 THEN DO;
    K = 500;
    NEWVAR_1 = PERCENTAGE * K;
    NEWVAR_2 = NEWVAR_1 * (VALUE_1 - 1);
    NEWVAR_3 = K + NEWVAR_2;
  END;
  ELSE IF _N_ GT 1 AND FLAG EQ 1 THEN DO;
    NEWVAR_1 = PERCENTAGE * LAG_NEWVAR_3;
    NEWVAR_2 = NEWVAR_1 * (VALUE_1 - 1);
    NEWVAR_3 = K + NEWVAR_2; 
    END;
  END;
  /* create temp retain variable */
  retain LAG_NEWVAR_3 0;
  drop LAG_NEWVAR_3;
  LAG_NEWVAR_3=NEWVAR_3;
RUN;
```

Documentation for lag function:  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212547.htm

Answer (score 1):

`LAG()` returns the value from the previous time that it ran. If you conditionally call `LAG()` then it will have a spotted recorded list of values.

Your logic can be simplified quite a lot.

```
DATA BACKTESTING;
  SET BACKTESTING;
  k = lag(newvar_3);
  IF _N_ EQ 1 then k=500 ;
  if FLAG EQ 1 THEN DO;
    NEWVAR_1 = PERCENTAGE * K;
    NEWVAR_2 = NEWVAR_1 * (VALUE_1 - 1);
    NEWVAR_3 = K + NEWVAR_2;
  END;
RUN;
```

But if NEWVAR_3 is really a "new" variable then it will be missing every time `lag(newvar_3)` runs and your lagged values will always be missing.  In that case you need to RETAIN the value from the previous observation.

```
DATA BACKTESTING;
  SET BACKTESTING;
  retain k 500 ;
  if FLAG EQ 1 THEN DO;
    NEWVAR_1 = PERCENTAGE * K;
    NEWVAR_2 = NEWVAR_1 * (VALUE_1 - 1);
    NEWVAR_3 = K + NEWVAR_2;
    k = newvar_3 ;
  END;
RUN;
```

Comment: Thanks @Tom for the explanation provided and the script examplification.